# parse json file recursively with JAVA

Tags: java, json

I have a json file that contains chapters which contain chapters and sub chapters .... it is not always the same number of chapters and sub chapters: For example

```
{
"IDCours" : "CS10.44",
"title": " .... ",
"chapters": [
    {
        "idChapter": "1",
        "title": "Introduction",
        "chapters": [
            {
                "idChapter": "1.1",
                "title": "basics",
                "content" : " blab bla blab "
            },
            {
                "idChapter": "1.2",
                "title": "basics",
                "content" : " blab bla blab "
            }                
         ]
      },
      {
      "idChapter": "2",
        "title": "..... ",
        "chapters": [
            {
                "idChapter": "2.1",
                "title": " .... ",
                "content" : " blab bla blab "
            },
            {
                "idChapter": "2.2",
                "title": ".....",
                "content" : " blab bla blab ",
                "chapters": [
                      {
                        "idChapter": "2.2.1",
                        "title": " .... ",
                        "content" : " blab bla blab "
                      }
                    ]   
            }              
         ]
        }
]
}
```

so, I think it should be done recursively because I don't know in advance how many chapters and sub-chapters, sub-sub chapters in the file

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post your Java code and what is not working like you expect.  This is likely to be closed for being too broad in the current state.

Comment: Any help for my problem ?

Comment: yes, post the code and what you have tried so far. I do not think someone will code an answer for you

Comment: It *is* done recursively, but by a JSON parser, not by you. All you need is one of the many JSON libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do it recursively. I usually use jackson library to work with Json's, so here how it could be done.

```
public class mainClass {
  String IDCours;
  String title; 
  List<Chapters> chapters;
    public static class Chapters {
      double idChapter;
      String title;
      List<InnerChapters> chapters;

        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        public static class InnerChapters {
          double idChapter;
          String title;
          String content;
          List<InnerChapters> chapters;
   }
 }
}
```

and use method to parse your json like:

```
public static final ObjectMapper objMapper;
static {
        objMapper= new ObjectMapper();
        objMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    }

public static <T> List<T> fromJsonToList(String json, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
        CollectionType customClassCollection = MAPPER.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, clazz);
        return objMapper.readValue(json, customClassCollection);
    }
```

@JsonIgnoreProperties annotation will ignore and not throw an exception if there will be no chapters list and keep parcing your json.
Try it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am new in coding and I don't know how to use the code that you posted, it is in the main class or where? Sorry for my questions and thank you for your help

Comment: You need to create new class, name it whatever you want. Plus you have to import Jackson library to use my code for parcing Json. And in advance: i don't think that it is a good idea to talk about recursive methods if you are "new in coding"

Comment: @oan I don't want to sound harsh, take it as the best advice, if you don't even know where should the code be put at, you should start with the basics first, before going into this "advanced" problems, start with console basic programs, then move into swing, then try web, and so on, or the learning curve will be harder, tells you a person that did the opposite and had harder time learning :)

Comment: @ BugsForBreakfast thank you for your advice, I will take it into account :) and sorry if I annoyed you